# Unable to overload '[ ]' in here. C++ Noob here

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am trying to implement a linkedlist in C++ and trying to incorporate array like data access using '[]'.

First I declared a Node class as the following.

```
class Node{
    public:
    int data;
    Node *next, *prev;
   
    Node(int val){
        this -> data = val;
        this -> next = NULL;
        this -> prev = NULL;
    }
};
```

Then I implemented the Linkedlist class as the following where I have overloaded the '[]' operator like the following

```
class LinkedList{
    public:
    Node *head;

    LinkedList(){
        this -> head = NULL;
    }

    LinkedList(Node *h){
        this -> head = h;
    }

    int operator [] (int index){
        if(index < 0 || index >= getsize(this -> head)){
            cout << "List out of bounds" << endl;
            return -1;
        }else{
            Node *cur = this -> getnode(index);
            return cur -> data;
        }
    }

    Node* getnode(int index){
        int count = 0;
        Node *cur = this -> head;
        while(cur != NULL){
            if(count == index)
                break;
            count++;
            cur = cur -> next;
        }
        return cur;
    }
};
```

In the main function I have tried to print the 'l[0]'. It shows error as

```
no operator "<<" matches these operandsC/C++(349)
linklist_sort.cpp(173, 10): operand types are: std::ostream << LinkedList
```

Please help me out. Am I missing some concept here ?

The main function :

```
int main(){

    srand(time(0));
    LinkedList *l = new LinkedList();

    for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
        int num = rand() % 50 + 1;
        l -> head = l -> insert(l->head,num);
    }

    l->printlist(l->head);

    int n1, n2;
    cout << "\n";
    cin >> n1 >> n2;
    l->swap(l->head,n1,n2);
    l->printlist(l->head);

    cout << "\n";
    cout << l[0]; //Error here
    return 0;
}
```

The getsize function :

```
int getsize(Node *head){
        if(head == NULL)
            return 0;
        else
            return 1 + getsize(head->next);
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your main function? Right now if I [fill in some blanks](https://godbolt.org/z/5Gcs1dGv3) and remove the `getsize` check that you don't show a definition for, I get expected output, so it sounds like the problem is with code you aren't showing.

Comment: Does that error even come from this code? I don’t see any use of << that way and the file name doesn’t sound right. Which line is 173 here?

Comment: Please take the [tour], read [ask] and then [edit] your question to contain a [mre].

Comment: @NathanPierson I have added the main function. Please check it out. I have also mentioned where the error is shown. The error is being shown in VSCode. In terminal the error is {linklist_sort.cpp:173:10: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream’ {aka ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’} and ‘LinkedList’)
}

Comment: `l` is a pointer, so `l[0]` doesn't use your operator. Don't use `new` to create objects. Alternatively, use `(*l)[0]`.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt it works thanks. I was trying something *l[0] which was showing an error . Thanks.

Comment: That's [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) for you. Since `[]` has higher precedence than `*`, `*l[0]` gets interpreted as `*(l[0])` instead of `(*l)[0]`.

Comment: `l[0][0]` would work as well, btw.

Comment: Yeah they work. Thanks a lot Ulrich and Nathan

Comment: C++ is not Java. `l` need not be a pointer and need not use `new`. Change to `LinkedList l;` and change all  `l->` in `main` to `l.`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since l is a pointer which is created by

`LinkedList *l = new LinkedList();`

it needs to be dereferenced to be able to use operator first.

This would solve your problem:
`cout << (*l)[0];`

But I suggest you to not create LinkedList with `new` keyword so you can avoid using raw pointers and memory leaks in the application code.
You could use `LinkedList l;`  instead.